# DryIoc ASP.NET 5 Web API

Tags: dnx50, dryioc

I'm trying to create a new Web API based on the ASP.Net 5 Web API template in VS2015, with DryIoc at container.
I've created a new Web API project and installed the DryIoc using package-manager

```
Install-Package DryIoc.Dnx.DependencyInjection -Pre
```

but I'm not sure how to wire up the container... haven't been able to find any 'Web API' samples showing that....

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a specific WebApi sample at the moment. But WebApi and Mvc are "unified" in AspNetCore, and I do have primitive [Mvc sample](https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/src/6f5496c12a8a7133bae20a5715773cd86979234b/DNX/DryIoc.Dnx.Mvc.Sample/?at=default). Hope it helps.

Btw, I am open for ideas / PRs how to improve it further.

Comment: Trying to make it work again, but now I get:  Unable to locate Dependency System.Runtime.Extensions >= 4.0.11-rc2-23706.

Comment: This AspNetCore proceeds moving, hopefully will stop with RC2. Meanwhile you can play with package versions, and ensure you have at least rc1-update1 installed. If your sample is on github, I can look.

Comment: Seems like the package version is referring System.Runtime.Extensions >= 4.0.11-rc2-23706

Comment: It is referring 4.0.11-*

Answer (score 4):

I've figured it out now...
The default startup.cs file contains:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

but it has to be replace with:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddMvc();
   var container = new Container().WithDependencyInjectionAdapter(services);
   container.Register<IRepository, Repository>(Reuse.Singleton);
   var serviceProvider = container.Resolve<IServiceProvider>();
   return serviceProvider;
}
```

also the ' System.Runtime.Extensions >= 4.0.11-rc2-23706' error can just be ignored